# .NET Core IIS websites stopped working HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: sitecore-commerce

After I updated vs2017 to the latest version this morning and uninstalled vs2019 Enterprise Preview (v16.0) and installed vs2019 Enterprise (v16.1), and installed the latest Windows updates all .NET Core 2.0.0 website no longer starting.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Complaining about web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 411a84e3-bdaa-45d8-89a2-b47670e591eb-->
```

Specifically regarding this element:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Line number: 10 Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/aspNetCore' cannot be read because it is missing section definition
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all .NET Frameworks and installed - it fixed the problem:

Runtime 2.2.4: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error and I fixed it installing `IIS Rewrite module`. Maybe it be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install .NET Core hosting bundle. It will install .NET runtime,.NET library and asp.NET core module.

The link to .NET core 2.1 hosting bundle is here:-

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer